# Jquery : how do i access the elements of a page that has been .load() into a new page

Tags: jquery

i am new to jquery but love it already ( i am a php programmer).

i have just use the .load() function to load content from another page to a new page. i am able to load the contents.

However, i now wish to accesssome elements of the newly loaded content but i am not able to do this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#signin a').click(function() {
     var url=$(this).attr('href');
      $('#loginpostion').load(url + ' #loginform');
      return false;


       $('#closebox a').click(function() {


        $('#loginpostion').removeClass()

      return false;


      }); //end click
```

i now  wish to access the following A tag from the newly loaded page: #closebox a

Is there anything that i need to do to let Jquery know that the "newly loaded content" will now form part of the DOM of the current page

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `return false;` line from your `$('#signin a').click()` handler function. It is causing execution to return before the second click handler (to `#closebox a`) is bound.

Comment: The `return false` is within the `click` handler. Her code needs two `})`.

Comment: @undefined - yes, but there is two of them?

Comment: @adeneo One for the first `click` handler and another one for `ready`.

Comment: @undefined - `ready` is'nt closed, the first is for the first click handler, and the second is for the second click handler, but it never gets there as it returns before the second click handler (it's inside the first).

Comment: @adeneo Correct, `ready` hasn't been closed, I think she just has forgotten to close/post the first and `last` `})`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate the function to a static parent element that exists on page load. We refer to this as 'Bubbling' or 'Event Propagation'. in jQuery's latest version, we use the `.on()` function to perform these actions.

```
$(document).on('click', '#closebox a', function(){

    $('#loginpostion').removeClass()

     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`load()` uses ajax, which is asynchronous so it loads in the background while your script keeps going. This means that when you are trying to access `#closebox` on the next line in your script, it does'nt yet exist as it has'nt been inserted into the DOM yet. You'll have to wait until the `load()` function is completed, and luckily `load()` has a callback function for this. Also, whenever you use return, the script ends and returns, so you'll have to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signin a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#loginpostion').load(url + ' #loginform', function() {
             $('#closebox a').click(function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $('#loginpostion').removeClass();
             });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: They both do the same thing, but I get your point - that using `event.preventDefault()` is better than `return false;` since it can occur anywhere in the callback, and is more explicit in what it does.

Comment: `return false` also stops propagation in jQuery, otherwise it's the same thing. I usually use `preventDefault` unless I intend to also stop propagation.

Comment: hi everyone . i tried the code above  but the .removeClass did not work. i tested the code. i.e i used an alert to see if the last click work, adn the alert worked. so, the problem is with the remove class. it is not removing the element.

Comment: `removeClass()` just removes a classname, not the entire element, and calling removeClass without specifying a class removes all classes that the element has attached to it. If you're trying to remove the entire `#loginpostion` element from the DOM, you should use `remove()` instead.

Comment: Hello again everyone. i have resolved the problem. The code now works. thank you so much to everyone for thier kind help in this matter. I HAVE ACTUALLY LEARNT A LOT FROM ALL THE GREAT COMMENTS THAT EVERYONE MADE

Answer (score 1):

you could eidther use the complete callback metod on the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signin a').click(function() {
        var url=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#loginpostion').load(url + ' #loginform', function() {
            $('#closebox a').click(function() {
                $('#loginpostion').removeClass()
                return false;
            }); //end click  
        });
    });
});
```

or you could use a delegate/live (if you aren´t using jquery 1.7+), if you want all your #closebox a elements that exists on the page now or in the future (with jquery and ofcouse then you cant have and id of #closebox) then you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#closebox a', click() {
        $('#loginpostion').removeClass();
        return false;
    });

    $('#signin a').click(function() {
        var url=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#loginpostion').load(url + ' #loginform');
        return false;
    });
});
```